# Multiple default gateways getting

Tags: c++, network-programming, mingw

i have a program in **C++** which is getting **Default Gateway**, so it works okay **until I try it on PC witch has few default gateways.** Here is my code:

```
DWORD Err,AdapterInfoSize =0;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo, pAdapt;
    if ((Err = GetAdaptersInfo(NULL, &AdapterInfoSize)) != 0) {
        if (Err != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW){
            std::cout<<"ERROR S05\n";
            cin.ignore();
        }
    }
    if ((pAdapterInfo = (PIP_ADAPTER_INFO) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, AdapterInfoSize)) == NULL) {
        std::cout<<"ERROR S06\n";
        cin.ignore();
    }
    if ((Err = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &AdapterInfoSize)) != 0) {
        std::cout<<"ERROR S07\n";
        cin.ignore();
    }
    pAdapt = pAdapterInfo;
    while (pAdapt){
        dfltgw = pAdapt->GatewayList.IpAddress.String;
        break;
    }
    pAdapt = pAdapterInfo;
    cout << endl << "DEFAULT GATEWAY: " << dfltgw << endl;
```

On **PC** where I have a **virtual network of VirtualBox** I always get output: **0.0.0.0** and on my PC where I have 1 Default Gateway I get the right IP.

So how can I fix it?

Comment: three things: 1. Welcome to Stack Overflow! 2. By definition of *default*, there can only be **exactly one** default gateway. I think you're confusing terms. 3. Modern browsers have support for spellchecking in English. I'm not a native speaker myself, so I promise it is very worth enabling that!

Comment: Thanks ,Okay, i will use splellchecker next time, so is there any way to get the real gateway of router?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding:

```
for (int izjson = 0; izjson < 50; izjson++) {
        string checkdf = pAdapterInfo->GatewayList.IpAddress.String;
        if(checkdf != "0.0.0.0") {
            dfltgw = checkdf;
            break;
        }
        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next; // Get next adapter info
    }
```

THANKS TO @SergeyA

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a list of all adapters installed in the system, but you are only checking the first one (your whole `while` loop is moot, you are breaking out of it after first iteration). Instead, you should iterate your adapters until you find the suitable one.

To answer some confusion in the comments, which assumes the default gateway is a global (and not per-adapter) setting, here is the copy-paste from ipconfig output:
Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4149:4c25:692d:dfec%91
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.252.26.84
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 14:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::79a2:afc8:7cd0:79ac%72
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.9
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
```

Comment: Still, "default gateway" is something related to routing of packets, not to individual interfaces. Ie. your OS figures out which interface to send a packet to by looking into the routing table, and using the default entry if nothing else matches. It's not like you tell your OS to send an IP packet "somewhere" over interface X; you tell it to send a packet to IP address 110.011.101.111 and based on that address your OS decides which interface to use!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, of course not. Default gateway is only meaningful for a particular interface. You are confused. OS 'does not figure out the interface', a socket is bound to the interface either explicitly or implicitly during `bind`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not, at least with respect to IPv4 routing. I must admit I'm not too deep into how Windows' network stack works internally, but I am 100% sure default gateway makes a lot of sense as a global routing aspect.

Comment: Imagine this: you're a userland program. You know you want to send a packet to 8.8.8.8, but you don't know which router to use. It's not your business to figure that out, so you give that packet to your OS. Your OS has a routing table that says "if no other entry matches, send the packet over interface X via 192.168.1.1". That makes sense.

Comment: No userland program will normally say "I want to send a packet to 8.8.8.8 using interface X", because it's not a userland program's job to know which interface to use. Hence, "default gateway" is a global routing aspect, not an interface-specific one, speaking from a IPv4 standard point of view.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, you are confused. To prove my point, here is a simple copy-paste from ipconfig output (posted in the answer to preserve formatting).

Comment: I know that Windows outputs that as "default gateway under the interface", it's just that no one else calls that default gateway. It's the gateway associated with the IP subnet that is associated with the interface.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, NO. This is because 'default gateway' is meaningful per-interface. Different interfaces have different default gateways. You can even see that OP was able to fix the problem using my suggestion. I am not sure what is your point. If you need further proof, consider the fact that default gateway is part of DHCP configuration. How do you think single default gateway would make sense for two independent adapters connected to two separated network?

Comment: good point, indeed. I'm intensely confused; as you noticed by my example of what happens when a random program sends a packet to a random IP address, I still presume there's a specific default routing entry.